# Behavior of :$\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty} n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}$ with $ k$ is natural number

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

I'm confused about behavior of this series  :$\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty} n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}$ with $k$ is natural number  , for $k=0 ,1$   the series converges according to wolfram alpha assumption however $k=0 ,1$ are  singular points , Now I want to know more about behavior of that series playing with  values of the integer $k$ , for $k=1$ the series converges and it gives:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}=\frac{1}{e-1}\tag{1}$$ and for $k=2$ we have :
$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}=\frac{1}{(e-1)e}\tag{2}$$ and for $k=3$ we have :
$$\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty} n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}=\frac{1}{(e-1)e^2}\tag{3}$$ , I have conjuctered that :
$$\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty} n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}=\frac{1}{(e-1)e^{k-1}}\tag{4}$$ , Now I 
have tow question :

**Question:01** :  Why [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum((1%2F++n+)%5E((n%2Flog+n)))),+n%3D0+to+infty) assumed that series converges for $k=0,1$ however they are singular points ?

**Question:02**

Does what i have conjuctered in $4$ true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The series is geometric: for $ n> 1$,
$$n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}=\exp\left(-\frac{n}{\log n}\cdot \log(n)\right)=(1/e)^n.$$

Comment: What about n=0,1 ?

Comment: For $n=0$ and $n=1$ the term $n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}$ is not defined.

Comment: But wolfram alpha assumed that convergent

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The singularities at $0$ and $1$ are removable and once removed, the series are defined as WA reports.

Comment: Yes, they are removable, but formally $n^{-\frac{n}{\log n}}$ is not defined at $0$ and at  $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$n^{-n/\log(n)}=e^{-n}$$

Now sum the geometric series